# Pointer returning from another class

Tags: c++

Alright so in Class A I have:

```
int* attackerDice;
int* defenderDice;
```

these two variables call on another class called dice. So:

```
attackerDice = dice.roll()
defenderDice = dice.roll()
```

what dice.roll does is the following:

```
int* Dice::roll () {
    int* ran = new int[1];
    srand(time(NULL));
    ran[0] = rand()%6+1;
    std::sort(ran,ran+1);
    return ran; 
}
```

Now the problem that I am getting is attackerDice is returning -43249211234 while defender dice is returning the right number. I assume this is because I clearly do not understand when to use * and &. Can anyone help me out?

Edit:
How would I go about doing this if I wanted to have an array? Id like to have it so that I can roll X number of dice

Comment: Why are you sorting an array with 1 element?

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating a single `int`? That uses more memory, will be error prone, and is slower than just returning an `int`. Why are you sorting an array with a single element?

Comment: `std::sort(ran,ran+1);` Huh? What's the purpose of this? You are trying to sort an array with a single element?

Comment: Oops. Sorry I was implementing it so that I could roll as many dice as I want and it would return them from largest to smallest. I wasn't finished though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much everything about your code is suboptimal:

- You are using dynamic allocation when there's really no need.
- You are allocating an array of a single element and sorting it (which makes no sense by the way).
- You are using `rand` which has been considered "evil" for quite some time now.
- You are putting an algorithm that does not use any member object of the class `Dice` as one of its member functions.

A revised "sane" solution would be the following:

```
namespace ex {
    class dice {
    private:
        std::mt19937 gen;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
    public:
        dice(int to)
            : gen(std::random_device()())
            , dis(1, to)
            {}

        int roll() { return dis(gen); }
    };
}
```

which would then be used as something like:

```
constexpr int count = 10;
std::vector<int> rolls;
rolls.reserve(count);

ex::dice dice(6);
std::generate_n(back_inserter(rolls), count, std::bind(&ex::dice::roll, dice));
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53fd7ddd062c24d4)

Comment: Very good notes. I refer to your example from my answer. However, there's some issues with using `<random>` like that remaining. +1 for the explanations though.

Comment: Thanks a lot ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ. I'm still very new to C++ so I had no clue rand was considered "evil". Ive been mainly programming in java up until now so I'm still learning the language.

Comment: Is it at all possible to nicely do this with an int array instead of a regular int? So that I can end up rolling multiple dice at one?

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball says that `Dice` doesn't obey [Rule Of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

It looks like you're having Undefined Behaviour because of mismanaged pointers and the lifetime of the objects they are pointing to.

In most cases, C++ doesn't require the use of pointers anyways.

> ***Don't Write `new` In C++***

See Jeffrey's answer for an idea how to avoid the lifetime issues.

Much better. Caution: It's very suboptimal to instantiate a new random generator each time through the loop, and using a uniform distribution like that is flawed. Instead, do:

```
auto dice = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>(1,6), mt19337 { random_device{}() });
```

Now you can just call

```
int roll1 = dice(); // roll1 = [1..6]
```

And it will actually be uniformly distributed as long as you use the same `dice` object

Comment: That single line `dice` object is pretty clever.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ Well the dice thing can be found on: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/. The real problem is here is that the singular for `dice` is actually `die`, and the function should read `int roll1 = die()`.

Comment: Hahaha. That was pretty funny